# Взаимодействие EZCAD3 через QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, api

Всем доброго дня. Возникла проблема в организации работы с маркировочным станком EZCAD3. Необходимо по нажатию одной кнопки запустить прожиг используя при этом 3 различных шаблона в формате (*.EZ3) последовательно. Все это дело работает через API функции. Станок на все запросы отвечает "OK", за исключением только одной команды "GetState" (не нее приходят ответ либо "OK:READY", либо "OK:MARKING").
Как организовать последовательность выполнения всех команд, при этом не перегрузив станок запросами (в этом случае приходит сообщение "FAIL:Error state").

Comment: Может быть периодически запрашивать состояние? Надо больше деталей о проблеме

Comment: вопрос связан не столько с программированием, сколько с функционированием конкретного устройства. по такому поводу лучше будет обратиться в техподдержку производителя устройства.